# restTemplate multi response structure

Tags: json, spring, rest

I need to call Rest web service using the GET method, the server will send 2 kind of response. when the request is processed with no business error it will send an object of type T. in case of business exception it will send an object of type E.

How can i call this web service using the  restTemplate.getForEntity(url, responseType) method and receive a response with T type or E Type dynamically. because as you can see the method accept only one type.

Comment: User a common superType for both of them ? or an `ExceptionHandler`

Comment: why do you need the E object ?, anyway there is a work around to this. use a wrapper  B that contains T and E , B{ T t; E e} .

Comment: Long live tunisia ;)

Comment: Long Live Tunisia.:)  In fact we use E as an exception object it will containt 3 attributs : error code, error message and detailed exception(technical). for the wrapper object i ithink it's a good idea. but i'am juste in the client side, for the server i can't change the structure of response and use wrapper class in the two sides(server and cleint)

Comment: do you have the responce type of the server ?

Comment: side server : in case of exception it send E object, otherwise it send T object just a list of items. but we are only in the client side and we must respect the specification implemented by the server

Answer (score 0):

In case of exception, the REST web service would be sending an error response, i.e. the code would not be 200, but 4** or 5**? If so, `RestTemplate` would use a `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` and throw an instance of `HttpStatusCodeException` with a method `getResponseBodyAsString()`. You can then use some converter to convert the string to a Java object.

Comment: in fact for security issue, our security team force(replace) the http status to 200, even if the application send 500 status.